# List all active promtail targets

Tags: prometheus

I have spend a significant time reading the manual, but I still cannot figure out how to actually get a list of the targets that promtail is currently tailing.

The metrics endpoint only exposes aggregate numbers.

How can I list all the targets promtail is currently tailing?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `${PROMTAIL_HTTP_ENDPOINT}/targets`. See [the server code](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/7edda371eae0e0a2535791ace6c87d7670cee925/clients/pkg/promtail/server/server.go#L126)